# Azure Bicep Error - Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, proxy, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy using bicep from a Powershell terminal in VSCode behind a corporate proxy.

My command line is:

```
az deployment sub create -f .\main.bicep -l uksouth
```

If I'm joined to the VPN then I get the following error:

```
Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/Azure/bicep/releases/latest (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x04BC0058>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')).
```

If I drop off the VPN then the error is:

```
Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/Azure/bicep/releases/latest (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))).
```

Any help on how to configure VSCode / PowerShell to make this work?

Comment: is it working from a powershell command outisde of VSCode ?

Comment: Same problem 

Comment: have you tried running `az bicep upgrade` ?

Comment: This gives the "(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines" error

Comment: Have you tried from another laptop ? I dont have any issue on my side

Comment: Yes, it works fine on my personal laptop. I'm sure it's a problem with the corporate proxy setup but thought it worth checking if anyone else had found a solution to the same problem.

Comment: Can you run any other az command like `az webapp list` when you are on connected to VPN ?

Comment: One of my clients had a similar issue. In our YAML Pipelines, we exposed a parameter `BicepVersion` with values of `v0.8.9`, `v0.5.6` and `latest`. Then further along in our pipeline at deployment or what-if stage, we ran the following azure-cli - `az bicep install --version $bicepVersion`. We found on our self hotsed agent and proxy, that V0.8.9 worked

Comment: This is caused due to a throttling issue on the github public API.  Apparently, it only allows 60 requests per hour from a single IP address.  This is very problematic when running builds from shared infrastructure.